# Forces on a helical screw?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, torque

The common screws which we use, are right handed helices, the simplest parametric equations of which are:-
$$x(s)=\cos(s),y(s)=\sin(s),z(s)=s$$, with $z$-axis as the axis of the helix.

[image]

My question is:-

> Why does a screw move forward or backward (forward for clockwise
>   rotation of a right-handed helix), on applying a pure rotational
>   torque?

Even if we provide only torque for rotation, i.e. force perpendicular to the axis, it moves along the axis. What force acting on it propels it forward? if it is a component of the normal reaction of the material it is driven into, what is the action-reaction pair for this normal reaction?

Comment: when a ring is spun around pencil it moves up. it is crude example of angular momentum. There is a toy which you move the fan blades up the helix its rotation increase thats also angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A screw acts exactly as an inclined plane. The perpendicular force decomposes and a longitudinal component is generated. This is balanced by an equal reaction of the material: for instance if you try to fasten a screw on a spaceship, as the screw moves forward, the spaceship will move a little backward.